# ModemManager warning messages

Tags: modem-manager

I am using an Ubuntu 16.04 version with ModemManager 1.6.4 on a Sierra Wireless EM74xx modem.

I did a couple of modem resets (`mmcli -m 0 --reset`) and the interface came up fine and got connected but with the following warning messages every 30 secs:

```
ModemManager[1111]: <warn>  Couldn't load extended signal information: Couldn't peek QMI port
```

What does the message mean and how can I resolve the same ?

Comment: source https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/modemmanager-next/+/factory-3004.B/src/mm-broadband-modem-qmi.c

Comment: are you sure you do not need "sudo" for this?

Comment: even with the sudo it gave the same errors but something to do with stale contexts in the ModemManager not getting cleared when reset happens.